# Passing function pointers of class members

Tags: c++

```
Service::serviceCtlHandler(DWORD OpCode)
{
  //...
}

Service::ServiceStart
{
  //...
  serviceStatusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler("Service", &Service::serviceCtrlHandler /*incompatible*/); 
  //...
}
```

How do I get a compatible pointer?

Comment: Make a free or static function and pass a pointer to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make your `serviceCtlHandler` function `static`, which means it won't be able to access any object members. This is because `RegisterServiceCtrlHandler` is expecting a function pointer which is not tied to an object and will not receive an implied `this` pointer.

If you use `RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx` instead, you can pass a pointer to the object and have the static function call another member function after properly casting the pointer.